# How to load files from internal storage Local Directories in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need help retrieving local image and video directories from internal storage for a gallery module in my Flutter app. I have an 'abc' folder in internal storage containing subfolders for images and videos, which I want to display in separate tabs with their file information (size and date) and thumbnails. Additionally, I require a video trimmer feature.

Is it possible to accomplish this in Flutter? Thank you for any assistance, devs. I have attempted to find a solution or package, but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

This is can be achieved with [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager), then you can style and group with gridview as you may prefer.

Yes, you trim videos in flutter, you can use [video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer) for that too.

Comment: Thanks for answering can i achieve file info like file size and date stored..?